# How to extract the color most used in image in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image-processing

I have got a project that needed image processing.In step 1 I need to get the color most used in image uploaded insde the application,anybody can help?

Comment: did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-color-picker ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [react-native-color-grabber](https://github.com/bsudekum/react-native-color-grabber) which is the closest resemblence to your problem :

It returns like this :

```
var colorGrabber = require('react-native').NativeModules.colorGrabber
colorGrabber.getColors(image, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
    // Returns:
    // {
    //  'UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.0784314 0.0941176 0.0823529 1': '0.1666667',
    //  'UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.215686 0.203922 0.262745 1': '0.1666667',
    //  'UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.517647 0.45098 0.380392 1': '0.6666667'
    // }
});
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: But this works only in ios,not android!
Do u know any tool for android?